# how to correct the path in linux

Tags: python, linux

I tried to install the python 2.7.3 on Linux box and then created alias in my local `.bash_profile`  as below:

```
alias python='/opt/python2.7.3/bin/python'
alias python2.7.3='/opt/python2.7.3/bin/python'

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/python2.7.3/bin
```

then run the command `source .bash_profile` to flush out all the update. but later I found the path was actually wrong and tried to correct it to the right one:

```
alias python='/opt/python2.7.3/bin/python2.7'    
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/python2.7.3/bin/python2.7
```

but when I export the path, it still has the wrong directory included though it does have the right one appended to the end. how I can get rid of the wrong directory from path totally?

Comment: try to set the path in `/etc/environment` file and then log out and log in.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you would want `/opt/python2.7.3/bin/python2.7` in your `$PATH`.  `$PATH` should only contain directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$PATH should contain directories, not a paths to binary files.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/python2.7.3/bin/
```